# $f$ being continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ $\implies$ $y' = f(y),y(t_0)=c$ has one global solution?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

By Picard's local existence theorem, if $f$ is locally Lipschitz, for any initial value problem, there is a **closed** interval $I = [t_0-\epsilon, t_0+\epsilon]$ such that 
$$y' = f(y), y(t_0) = c$$
has one solution on $I$.

Now my reasoning is that if we take the new initial value problem
$$x' = f(x),x(t_0+\epsilon) = y(t_0+\epsilon)$$

It again has a solution on a new closed interval. $x(t_0+\epsilon) = y(t_0+\epsilon)$, so by uniqueness they should be the same! We can do this arbitrarily many times, which would imply a global, unique solution (keep extending the original solution $y$ with the solutions of the new initial value problems).

This seems way too strong, so I think I must have an error in my logic somewhere. Is there?

Comment: Your closed intervals need not cover all of $\mathbb{R}$, they might just cover an open interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classical counter example:
$$
f(y)=y^2\implies y(t)=\frac{c}{1-ct}
$$
which has a pole at $t=\frac1c$.

You need to take into account that the interval length may depend on the initial point $(t_0,y_0)$, $y_0=c$, so that rather than a constant $ϵ$ you get a sequence $ϵ_n$ and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty ϵ_n<\infty
$$
is well possible.